# Shared folder not connecting over Mac VirtualBox guest

Tags: windows, macos, mac, virtualbox, smb

I am trying to connect with the Windows 7 host's shared folder from my VirtualBox Mac (Yosemite) guest. It is showing my PC's name in Finder's sidebar but when I double click it, it fails to connect to my PC/shared folder. Image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Virtual Guest Additions** are required to be installed on your virtual machine in order to use *Shared folders*. These can be installed by selecting *Insert Guest Additions CD Image* from the *Devices* menu of your guest VM window.

[image: Devices menu, Insert Guest Additions CD Image...]

Comment: Apple's SLA disallows using MacOS guests on not Mac hosts. So tools like Virtual Guest Additions (for MacOS) are not available in distributions made for Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a **"half-solution"** for the same problem. I made **".iso"** image and connect it to the guest OS as CD. The disadvantage is a one way direction from Host to Guest but for me it was ok because I needed to pass some files for testing.